# MS Outlook is removing hidden text in reply email

Tags: html, email, outlook, tags, hidden

We have Ruby script that fetch and parse reply emails from our clients and putting them on appropriate client object in application.

For that purpose we send email to client with specific "hidden" code/id inside 1x1 pixel img tag (in similar way tracking pixel technology works) when clients reply to email, they quote our original email with code/id inside. And when we get client reply we can detect that hidden code from img tag, and process it accordingly. This works fine except when clients are replying from Outlook 2013.

Outlook 2013 removes image data containing code/id, and put something like "Image removed by sender." so we cannot detect see code/id anymore.
Also tried, making a image from base64 and even encoding code/id inside base64 image, but we got same result.

We tried different solutions, like making custom tags with class name contain code/id. Those custom tags are removed too, and replaced with something like < o:p >< /o:p >

We tried to put code/id inside invisible div, in inline css and various css tricks, and in this case Outlook just removes invisibility of div, and code/id is visible in email content.

There is a option that code/id is visible text inside body or subject, but we would like that this code/id be stays invisible to the clients.

It seems like its almost impossible to pass some hidden data trough reply email from MS Outlook.

Is there any way that we can pass this code/id trough reply email from outlook, without outlook removing it or making it visible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the data is visible (one way or another), chances are Outlook (or rather Word-light used for editing emails) will remove it.

White text on white background would probably work...

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src=3D"https://t.yesware.com/t/58c8a29bcdf01103c9661815ef20eff8d=
f34a1b3/556ad713ae0cb0b15199a455f1fa5dfd/spacer.gif" style=3D"border:0; wid=
th:0; height:0; overflow:hidden;" width=3D"0" height=3D"0"><img src=3D"http=
://t.yesware.com/t/58c8a29bcdf01103c9661815ef20eff8df34a1b3/556ad713ae0cb0b=
15199a455f1fa5dfd/spacer.gif" style=3D"border:0; width:0; height:0; overflo=
w:hidden;" width=3D"0" height=3D"0">
```

**I will address this dry-snitching code in a bit**

Yesware is a paid service that allows you to track when and where the recipient of your email opens that email, every single time that they do or if they forward it to someone else, you will get the IP address and device type of each of those opens as well.

I've used Yesware for years, this is the first time that it has peeked it's little head out. In an email chain involving my Gmail hosted email and someone we will call Quarles. The first email I sent Quarles went normally, I received notification from Yesware that Quarles opened it from an iPhone. No further notifications came from YesWare which is impossible because he has replied twice.

I discovered in the latest email thread, under my second reply, **Image removed by sender.Image removed by sender.**
Below my third reply, **Error! File name not specified.Error! Filename not specified.**

I viewed the headers and, damn the luck, Quarles is using Outlook on a Mac *Microsoft-MacOutlook/10.c.0.180410*

What I am curious about is what Quarles sees on his end. Because the gif is not gone, the code is still there in our thread untouched. I know because if I open the email thread from another device (non-sending device) I get the notification that someone opened the email. So, **what is preventing the code from calling home? Is it his MacOutlook? Is it an add-on he's got?**

I am seriously considering having my husband write something better than Yesware. He's not a programmer but he is a SysAdmin so he'll figure it out. Besides, the stupid programs he has designed looked like crap anyway so why not write code **for something that is supposed to remain unseen.**

Oops, gotta go, if he catches me on stackoverflow he's gonna freak.. ;)